# How to return exactly one document per match in bool

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with a (simplified) structure like this:

```
{uuid: 1, timestamp: "2017-10-18T01:30:00.000Z", "key": "value"}
{uuid: 2, timestamp: "2017-10-18T01:30:00.000Z", "key": "value"}
{uuid: 1, timestamp: "2017-10-18T01:25:00.000Z", "key": "value"}
{uuid: 2, timestamp: "2017-10-18T01:25:00.000Z", "key": "value"}
{uuid: 1, timestamp: "2017-10-18T01:20:00.000Z", "key": "value"}
{uuid: 2, timestamp: "2017-10-18T01:20:00.000Z", "key": "value"}
```

Now I'm trying to get **exactly one** document per `uuid` match like so (with the latest timestamp):

```
query: {
    bool: {
        should: [{
            match: {
                uuid: 1
            }
        },
        {
            match: {
                uuid: 2
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

However, the above query returns multiple documents for both `uuid`s. How do I modify my query to return two latest documents with `uuid` `1` and `2` like so:

```
{uuid: 1, timestamp: "2017-10-18T01:30:00.000Z", "key": "value"}
{uuid: 2, timestamp: "2017-10-18T01:30:00.000Z", "key": "value"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a `terms` aggregation coupled with a `top_hits` sub-aggregation, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "uuid.keyword": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "uuid.keyword": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "uuids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "uuid.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "timestamp": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This query results with the following error message: `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Expected [START_OBJECT] under [field], but got a [VALUE_STRING] in [terms]","line":1,"col":99}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Expected [START_OBJECT] under [field], but got a [VALUE_STRING] in [terms]","line":1,"col":99},"status":400}`

Comment: My bad... fixed!

Comment: Now ES whines about "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default". Should I enable it on `uuid` field?

Comment: can you try `uuid.keyword` in the terms aggregation instead? According to your sample data, it didn't look like the `uuid` field was a string, though.

Comment: I invited you for a chat on SO so we can (hopefully) discuss the solution

Comment: I've a similar problem with a difference that in my case I wont be knowing the `"uuid.keyword": 1` and `"uuid.keyword": 2` beforehand and I do not know how many of such values will be there. How can I achieve this? I've another thread open for it here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50095867/2642351 . Kindly advice.