# Find top 5 documents from each unique bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

Let us say that I've a number of ElasticSearch documents like the sample given below:

```
 {
    "Tagname": [
        "Veniam"
    ],
    "Title": [
        "Occaecat do. Eu ut."
    ]
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
  {
    "Tagname": [
        "Anim"
    ],
    "Title": [
        "Consectetur dolor consectetur eu."
    ]
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
  {
    "Tagname": [
        "Aliqua"
    ],
    "Title": [
        "Culpa in ut ut. Enim in excepteur eiusmod."
    ]
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Here, lets assume that `Tagname` is the name of the tag under which every `Title` falls. And `Tagname` is mapped as a `keyword`, such that when I aggregate on the `Tagname.keyword`, I get for example 3 unique `TagName` buckets (Veniam, Anim, Aliqua, etc...). In my case lets assume we do not have a fixed number of unique `TagName` and it might change dynamically. So, we can not assume a static list of unique `TagName` in our search query.

What I want to achieve now is to get top 5 `Title` values under each of these buckets. (So far a sorting or ordering of any sort to get the top 5 is not essential, and random 5 would also work. However an explanation for the sorting would be enlighting.)

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806980/how-to-return-exactly-one-document-per-match-in-bool/46807068#46807068 (hint use `top_hits` with `size:5` )

Comment: This answer is useful in case of static terms. However, in my case its dynamic and I have to depend on aggregate query to find unique values. Hence, your suggestion will not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by static vs dynamic terms?

Comment: meaning, the `"uuid.keyword": 1` and `"uuid.keyword": 2` are fixed in the query. However, in my case, I do not know how many and what will be the values of the keywords. Hence, mine will be dynamic whereas the example you shared is static (or fixed values). I will only get the values from aggregation query. I was expecting may be there is a way where, we can pass the buckets in the result of the aggregation into the `should` of the query.

Comment: Then don't add any query, it's completely optional. In your `terms` aggregation add (e.g.) `size: 100` (or a number at least as big as the cardinality of the `Tagname` field) in order to make sure to get all values.

Comment: Brilliant! your advice worked it seems. Thanks @Val. I see the `"hits"` block appearing in the result. Can you tell me if there is a way to remove the entire hits block from the result, such that I only have the `"aggregations"` block in the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170125/discussion-between-temp-orary-and-val).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the following aggregation. I've used an arbitrary size of 100, but you can replace that by the cardinality of your `Tagname` field, so as to make sure that you get one bucket per value of `Tagname`. Then, you have a nested `top_hits` aggregation that will return you 5 documents for each bucket.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Tagname.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I do not use "size": 100 is there a default limit? What is the default limit?

Comment: The default number of buckets coming back is 10 or less if the cardinality of your field is lower.

Comment: You seem to be very knowledgeable about ElasticSearch, Let me tell you that I'm new to ElasticSearch. Can you kindly advice me of any great resource from where I can learn ElasticSearch stack?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) is a great resource. You might also want to check out the [Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) which is more comprehensive and probably better to start with.