# Elasticsearch : Searching grouped results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a catalog of products from various categories - Shirts, Trousers, Shoes etc. loaded in an elasticsearch index.

I want to support a use case to allow searching products by their name and get the results grouped by categories. For example, when I search "Red" I would like to see top 5 Red shirts, top 5 Red Trousers, top 5 Red Shoes

I found a way to do this using top hits aggregation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806980/how-to-return-exactly-one-document-per-match-in-bool/46807068#46807068). But I am not sure if that is the right way to progress. This is a 2 level aggregation and I'm worried this will make the query slow.

Is there a better (faster?) way to achieve this?

Edit : Adding Sample data

Sample catalog

```
[
    {
        "title": "Red Shirt",
        "category": "Shirt",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "title": "Blue Shirt",
        "category": "Shirt",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "title": "Green Shirt",
        "category": "Shirt",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "title": "Black Shoes",
        "category": "Shoes",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "title": "White Shoes",
        "category": "Shoes",
        "id": 5
    },
    {
        "title": "Red Shoes",
        "category": "Shoes",
        "id": 6
    },
    {
        "title": "Red and White Shoes",
        "category": "Shoes",
        "id": 7
    },
    {
        "title": "Red Bag",
        "category": "Bag",
        "id": 8
    },
    {
        "title": "Red and Blue Bag",
        "category": "Bag",
        "id": 9
    },
    {
        "title": "Yello Bag",
        "category": "Bag",
        "id": 10
    }
]
```

Expected response when searching for "red"

```
[
    {
        "category": "Shirt",
        "results": [
            {
                "title": "Red Shirt",
                "category": "Shirt",
                "id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Shoes",
        "results": [
            {
                "title": "Red Shoes",
                "category": "Shoes",
                "id": 6
            },
            {
                "title": "Red and White Shoes",
                "category": "Shoes",
                "id": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Bag",
        "results": [
            {
                "title": "Red Bag",
                "category": "Bag",
                "id": 8
            },
            {
                "title": "Red and Blue Bag",
                "category": "Bag",
                "id": 9
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: @ESCoder I've added the sample data and expected response for a query